# How to write hql/sql to solve below problem

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

I am trying to write a below code to achieve the output?

Input :

```
+----------------------+
|         dttm         |
+----------------------+
| 2014-11-18 16:23:01  |
| 2014-11-18 16:23:02  |
| 2014-11-18 16:26:14  |
| 2014-11-18 16:26:15  |
| 2014-11-18 16:26:16  |
| 2014-11-18 17:43:02  |
| 2014-11-18 17:43:03  |
| 2018-12-17 23:59:59  |
| 2018-12-18 00:00:00  |
| 2019-01-17 00:00:00  |
| 2019-01-17 00:00:01  |
+----------------------+
```

Output :

```
+----------------------+
|         dttm         |
+----------------------+
| 2014-11-18 16:23:01  |
| 2014-11-18 16:23:02  |
| 2014-11-18 16:26:14  |
| 2014-11-18 16:26:15  |
| 2014-11-18 16:26:16  |
| 2014-11-18 16:26:16  |
| 2014-11-18 17:43:02  |
| 2014-11-18 17:43:03  |
| 2018-12-17 23:59:59  |
| 2018-12-18 00:00:00  |
| 2019-01-17 00:00:00  |
| 2019-01-17 00:00:01  |
+----------------------+
```

Implementation logic : Line item 1 and 2 should have difference of 1 sec, 3 and 4 should have difference of 1 sec and so on.

If it is not the case, duplicate that line item.

Comment: Can you show some negative scenarios as well?

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please let me know what information you are looking for?

Comment: Please ignore the above comment. I have got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select a.dttm from (
select   t1.rn, t1.dttm, case when  (unix_timestamp(t2.dttm) - unix_timestamp(t1.dttm) )  = 1 then '1' when  (unix_timestamp(t2.dttm) - unix_timestamp(t1.dttm)) is null then '1' else '1,2' end as split_rec
from (select dttm, row_number () over () as rn from tmstmp) t1 left outer join
(select dttm, row_number () over () as rn from tmstmp) t2
on t1.rn = t2.rn-1 and pmod(t2.rn,2) =0) a
lateral view explode(split(a.split_rec , ',')) temp as td1
;



Output is :

+-----------+------------------------+--+
| temp.td1  |         a.dttm         |
+-----------+------------------------+--+
| 1         | 2014-11-18 16:23:01.0  |
| 1         | 2014-11-18 16:23:02.0  |
| 1         | 2019-01-17 00:00:00.0  |
| 1         | 2019-01-17 00:00:01.0  |
| 1         | 2014-11-18 16:26:14.0  |
| 1         | 2014-11-18 16:26:15.0  |
| 1         | 2014-11-18 16:26:16.0  |
| 2         | 2014-11-18 16:26:16.0  |
| 1         | 2014-11-18 16:26:16.0  |
| 1         | 2014-11-18 17:43:02.0  |
| 1         | 2014-11-18 17:43:03.0  |
| 1         | 2018-12-17 23:59:59.0  |
| 1         | 2018-12-18 00:00:00.0  |
+-----------+------------------------+--+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I can see `2014-11-18 16:26:16' coming thrice. Can you please double check?

Comment: Could be because of input data. I have inserted twice by mistake. Pls give a try on actual data and validate. Thanks